# Azure Api Apps with authentication in Swift

Tags: swift, wcf, azure, authentication, alamofire

I have published an Azure Api App that I consume in my iOS App in Swift, but my problem is that this API is public and don't need any authentication to access it.
The only way I found to protect my API is to use Azure Active Directory for authentication. But now the issue is that I no longer manage to consume this API from my iOS App. 
I use Alamofire but I don't really understand how the connection works.

Any clues about it ? :D

Thank you very much !!!

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways Microsoft provides to authenticate.  The "old" way is using [ADAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) and the "new" way is [MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-libraries).

There are sample apps on many technologies including iOS (in Objective-C) on those links.

Is important to be carefull about ATS (Apple Transport Security) which blocks non https requests.  Search on Google this: "*Configuring App Transport Security Exceptions in iOS 9 and OSX 10.11*" which explains how to set up ATS exceptions.